# How to configure freeIPA in multi domain environment?

Tags: freeipa

I am having several servers in different domains.

Example: 6 systems in domain abc.com (server1.abc.com, server2.abc.com ... server6.abc.com) and 5 systems in domain xyz.com (server1.xyz.com, server2.xyz.com ... server5.xyz.com)
All the client machines are running in another domain example.com and each domain is in a different subnet.

I want to setup freeIPA such that users in example.com can connect to any server in domain
abc.com and xyz.com using SSO.

How should I proceed with the setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all those systems are enrolled to IPA realm EXAMPLE.COM and use sssd, the scenario should work.

SSSD pulls in all domains defined on IPA and maps them to IPA realm. Alternatively you can map them to IPA realm yourself if no SSSD is in use. It is all in krb5.conf. Hence, IPA systems can be in any domains, krb5.conf contains domain/realm mapping for this purpose, all they need to know is how to find IPA's KDC, the systems themselves do not have to belong to "exmpale.com" domain.

Hope this helps.